# Strategy to distinguish a rank 2 vector bundle from an extension class group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

If you think this question is very basic, then I apologies my ignorance at the first stance.

Suppose $V$ is a rank 2 vector bundle on a rational ruled surface $\pi:\mathrm{X}=:\mathbb{P}(\cal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}\oplus\cal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1))\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1$. Then we may find a canonical extension for $V$ as
$$
0\to \mathrm{L}\to\mathrm{V}\to\mathrm{L'}\otimes\mathrm{I}_Z\to 0,
$$
where $\mathrm{L}, \mathrm{L'}$ are line bundles and $\mathrm{I}_Z$ is an ideal sheaf for a 0-cycle $Z$.
Then $V$ is parametrized by a projective space $\mathbb{P}\,\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathrm{L'}\otimes\mathrm{I}_Z,\mathrm{L})$ in the weak isomorphism sense. If the dimension of vector space $\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathrm{L'}\otimes\mathrm{I}_Z,\mathrm{L})$ is less than or equal to 1, we can conclude that $V$ is split (when it corresponds to 0) or a unique nontrivial vector bundle fitted into the above extension.

Here is the question :
If the dimension of $\mathbb{P}\,\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathrm{L'}\otimes\mathrm{I}_Z,\mathrm{L})$ is larger than 1, then how distinguish the original vector bundle $V$ from the other (nonisomorphic) bundles that comes from the same extension?

Is there any book or paper deal with the similar problem?

Thank you for any advice or comment.

Comment: The book Okonek, Christian; Schneider, Michael; Spindler, Heinz. "Vector bundles on complex projective spaces" is a good reference for this kind of questions.

Comment: Sasha, thank you for your comment. I think the book does not content precisely what I want. But it is actually helped so many aspects. If whoever have any other recommend, please comment me. Thank you.